# Copy the newest dir to a network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

Dear all,
I want to create a schedule job in windows which will copy the newest directory with its file to a specified network path. I want fist to zip this dir and then to copy to the network path. SO under a specific directory a program creates a dir as follows: 0001, 0002, 003, etc. So I want the BAT file to take the last created one, zip it and copy it to the network drive \elias\cd1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And at which point your code fails?

Answer (score 0):

Please look here: [windows bat script to compress and move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585566/looking-for-a-windows-bat-script-to-compress-and-move-log4j-log-files) and skip step 4.

Only thing left to fit in, is to find the last subdirectory, which you can do as follows:

```
set dirtoprocess=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b/o-d`) do if exist "%%~f\" (
    set dirtoprocess="%%~f"
    goto :OK
)
::UHOH, no directory found…
goto :EOF
:OK
::continue…
```